# Public CDN for CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, cdn, google-cdn

Simple one:
Is there any public CDN to load CKEditor like when you load jQuery from Google's CDN?

I haven't been able to find any big CDN. I guess I could always hotlink to ckeditor.com's JS file but that's not exactly what optimization means.

Comment: Yes. See: https://pagecdn.com/lib/ckeditor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://cdn.ckeditor.com

It is the **official CDN for CKEditor**, hosted by Amazon CloudFront and with SSL support. More information about using CDN and/or available types of releases can be found on [CKEditor CDN Website](http://cdn.ckeditor.com).

Answer (score 22):

You can submit it to http://www.cdnjs.com/ but its is not there yet.

**Edit:** Now is has been added: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js

Comment: Cool! Does this contain only the JS file? or also the css files and translations etc...

Comment: update: tested and yes it includes the default config settings, with CSS files and images!

Answer (score 6):

It seems available at jsdelivr.com
http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!ckeditor

Comment: This has the latest version and separate scripts for all plugins!

Comment: thank you but I don't consider MAXCDN a real CDN since they don't have any servers in South America (where most of my users are) and they don't plan to.

Answer (score 0):

Links of public CDN for CKEditor

1. https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ (Official)
2. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ckeditor
3. https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [CKEditor CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/ckeditor) is available just like Google CDN. Here is a quick snippet to include it in your HTML.

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/ckeditor/4.13.0/ckeditor.js" integrity="sha256-yoULaG5POtLMfQWKvJ1pCbUSX4eM29SBpDbjkZAK6qs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```