# How do I get CKEditor working from the CDN?

Tags: javascript

How do I get CKEditor working from the CDN?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6MeW)

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I have included the JS and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795258/public-cdn-for-ckeditor) it says that is enough.
But I dont seem to get it working :(
Please help!

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/e6MeW/2/

**Error**: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ckeditor'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put [this](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js) url to External Resource on jsfiddle;

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.replace($('.ckeditor').get(0), {
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7m8H/